# Flowplayer 5.2 Dynamic URL

Tags: html, flash, url, dynamic, flowplayer

Had a question/issue I could use your assistance on:

I adapted the example of flowplayer 3.2.15 to pull in a dynamic URL and create a new flowplayer for that video each time the function is called. It works great, here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Flowplayer playlist API : Flowplayer</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://flash.flowplayer.org/favicon.ico">
<style>
    body{
        width:982px;
        margin:50px auto;
        font-family:sans-serif;
    }
    a:active {
        outline:none;
    }
    :focus { -moz-outline-style:none; }

    .palert {
        padding: 12px;
        color: black;
        background-color: #ededed;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    #player {
    width:425px;
    height:330px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 40px 20px;
}
</style>

<script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer-3.2.11.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer.playlist-3.2.10.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>

function showVideoPreview(videoUrl)
{
    $(function() 
    {           
        flowplayer("player", "flowplayer-3.2.15.swf", {clip: { url: videoUrl, scaling: 'fit' }});
    });
}

showVideoPreview('http://www.tools4movies.com/trailers/1012/A%20Good%20Day%20To%20Die%20Hard.mp4');

</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="playlist.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<button onClick="showVideoPreview('http://www.tools4movies.com/trailers/1012/Alex%20Cross.mp4');">Recreate</button>
<div id="player"></div>
<br clear="all"/>
</body>
</html>
```

However, because it is 3.2.15 it does not work for HTML5. So I wanted to upgrade this code to work with 5.2. I tried taking the 5.2 example and applying the same logic but the video never shows up and no javascript errors are displayed. Can anyone provide some guidance or help? Here is what I tried:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skin/minimalist.css" />
<style>
body { font: 12px "Myriad Pro", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; text-align: center; padding-top: 5%; }
#player {
    width:425px;
    height:330px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 40px 20px;
}
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.2.1/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showVideoPreview(videoUrl)
{
    $(function() 
    {           
        flowplayer("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.2.1/flowplayer.swf", {clip: { url: videoUrl, scaling: 'fit' }});
    });
}

showVideoPreview('http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.mp4');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flowplayer" id="player" data-swf="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.2.1/flowplayer.swf"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much guys, I appreciate it.

Comment: I never received any ideas/solutions from this so I'd recommend trying a different tool if you need to change video URL's dynamically and want it in HTML5/Flash.